# Could Harry's child inherit part of Voldemort's powers?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

If Harry Potter had a child **while he was a Horcrux**, would this child have some of Voldemort's powers?

(For instance, would it be a Parselmouth?)

Comment: I'm not sure if this isn't more opinion based or not. On one hand, he could inherit Harry's Powers, meaning Voldemort. The thing is, when Harry 'died', the connection to Voldy was severed, and as such that would make it so there wasn't a connection anymore, causing the Children to be normal...ish

Comment: Genetics are notoriously iffy in the Potterverse, but since the piece of soul lodged inside Harry (he wasn’t an actual Horcrux, by the way) was just that: a sliver of a _soul_, it seems unlikely that it would have any real, genetic effect on him. It affected his own abilities, which are (presumably) a direct result of how your own brain and soul cooperate and work; but for his children to be able to inherit it, it would have to actually be able to modify his genetic makeup. So my guess would be no—but it’s only a guess with nothing to back it up, which is why this is only a comment. :-]

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Also, the piece of Volemort's soul was killed by Voldemort himself, so that piece of him no longer existed by the time Harry and Ginerva had their first child. Also, when Voldemort killed his own piece of soul, it also removed the abilities Harry had (such as Parseltongue).

Comment: @Anoplexian The assumption is part of the question here: “If Harry Potter had a child **while he was a Horcrux**”. Say he and Ginny had managed a bit more private time in that makeshift student rebel base in the Room of Requirement before the whole battle thing happened—that’s the scenario we’re going for here.

Comment: At that point it gets to be more opinion based sort of "what if" scenario. We clearly can tell when they got busy by the age of their children, and the year of their marriage. Per the HP wiki, the 2nd Wizarding war ended in 1998, and then Ginny and Harry were married sometime in the 2000's. Their first child James Potter was born somewhere in 2003. Even if those numbers are slightly off, the 2nd Wizarding War and the loss of Harry's abilities were long gone by the time Harry and Ginerva had a child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the answers [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27613/would-harry-still-be-a-parselmouth-at-the-end-of-the-deathly-hallows/) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37252/did-harry-potter-lose-voldemorts-powers-when-he-stopped-being-a-horcrux), Harry looses his Voldemort related abilities, including the ability to speak parseltongue, at the time that the part of Voldemort's that lived within Harry was destroyed. This being said, these traits were not part of Harry's gene pool, and therefore would not be passed on to his children.

Answer (score 2):

## No - those powers are directly linked to the piece of soul in Harry.

If Harry had a child while he was a Horcrux, the child wouldn’t then inherit any of the Dark Lord’s powers from him, since Harry himself only had them because a piece of the Dark Lord’s soul was in him. The child wouldn’t have a piece of the Dark Lord’s soul, so wouldn’t have any of his powers.

> “Part of Lord Voldemort lives inside Harry, and it is that which gives him the power of speech with snakes, and a connection with Lord Voldemort’s mind that he has never understood.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 33 (The Prince’s Tale)*</sup></sub>

Once the piece of the Dark Lord’s soul is gone, Harry no longer has his powers, further proving that his powers in Harry are directly linked to the soul piece, and won’t exist in Harry without it.

> **Nigel:** Can harry speak parseltongue when he is no longer a horcrux?
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** No, he loses the ability, and is very glad to do so. 
> <sub><sup>*[- J.K. Rowling and the Live Chat, Bloomsbury.com (July 30, 2007)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html)*</sup></sub>

Since the soul piece would still remain in Harry if he had a child, and the child wouldn’t have its own piece of the Dark Lord’s soul, the child also wouldn’t have any of the Dark Lord’s powers.